# How can I validate I have drawn something in jSignature panel or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`jSignature` is having canvas and it has a class. How can I validate jSignature whether I have drawn something or not ?

I have added one bind for click event.

```
$sigdiv.bind('click', function(e) {
    $("#num_strok").val(parseInt($("#num_strok").val()) + 1);
});
```

Problem is even I click some corner also `num_strock` get increases. And for some dragging it will not increase.

I have tried in Google whether it has any built in `isEmpty` function is there or not. But I have not found anything.

Answer (score 23):

```
 if( $sigdiv.jSignature('getData', 'native').length == 0) {
    alert('Please Enter Signature..');
 }
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach. It doesn't require any additional jSig plugins, extra bindings, or any flags to maintain.

Comment: this works ok for the native option. but others like svgbase64 won't.

Answer (score 5):

Very late to the party... So I wanted to give some input on my findings, each related to 
using `$("#sigDiv").jSignature('getData', 'putSomethignInHere')` function to validate the a signature is present.

Here are the options I have examined for the second attribute passed into the jSignature function:

`native` returns an object of objects `.length == 0` when the sig box is empty, but `.length > 0` when there is something in the sig box. If you want to know how many strokes just use the length of this object. 
NOTE: According to the jSignature documentation:

> "Stroke = mousedown + mousemoved * n (+ mouseup but we don't record that as that was the "end / lack of movement" indicator)"

`base30` also returns an object. Here I looked at the information in the second index position of this object. 
`x = $("#sigDiv").jSignature('getData', 'base30')[1].length > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE` Here `x` would yeild TRUE if the box has been signed and FALSE when the jSig box is left untouched.

In my case, I used the `base30` attribute for validating signature **complexity**, not just "did the end user draw something?".
`x = $("#sigDiv").jSignature('getData', 'base30')[1].length > {insertValueHere} ? TRUE : FALSE`. To validate the end user actually signed in the box and gave more than a simple '.' of small 'x'. The return value of the second index yielded from `base30` gets larger as the complexity. Thus, if the user did enter just a dot, 
`x = $("#sigDiv").jSignature('getData', 'base30')[1].length` would be about 5. The yielded value just get larger and larger the more the end user draws in the box. The highest lenght I recorded during my testing was 2272. And I scribbled and scribbled in the box for all of 15 secounds.

According to the jSig documentation:

> base30 (alias image/jSignature;base30) (EXPORT AND IMPORT) (VECTOR) data format is a Base64-spirited compression format tuned for absurd compactness and native url-compatibility. It is "native" data structure compressed into a compact string representation of all vectors.

`image`- this is a choice I would avoid for validation. It produces an object with a long string in the second index position. The last one I measured was 672 characters long.  Using `image` produces a string regardless whether the sig box is blank or used. And to make things more unuseful, the string produced is different for a blank signature box in Chrome verse a blank signature box in FF Developer. I'm sure the `image` value has a use, but just not validation.

`svgbase64` - this is similar to `image` with exceptions. Unlike `image`, using `svgbase64` produces a long -yet shorter- string in the second position. Also, this string IS the same when I performed the Chrome verse FF Developer check. This is where I stopped my testing. So I assume you can use `svgbase64` for validation.

These are my conclusions, yours may vary. Please don't hold my low reputation against me.

Comment: Great in-depth response. Using [base30] definitely gives a better indication of signature complexity. I settled on a threshold of 75.

Comment: `$("#sigDiv").jSignature('getData', 'base30')[1].length`  gives `0` only for `base30` other format such as `svgbase64` returns 132

Answer (score 4):

According to the [jSignature website](http://willowsystems.github.com/jSignature/#/about/) there is a `getData` function in the API. If you use the `getData` function on an empty signature area as reference, you could then use `getData` whenever you want and compare it to the empty reference. You would then be able to tell if something has been written in the signature area.

This is just a guess from my part, as I haven't used this script, but I think something like this would be able to work.

### EDIT

I also found this on [the website](http://willowsystems.github.com/jSignature/#/about/)

> The dom element upon which jSignature was initialized emits 'change'
>   event immediately after a stroke is done being added to the storage.
>   (In other words, when user is done drawing each stroke. If user draws
>   3 strokes, this event is emitted 3 times, after each stroke is done.)
>
> Here is how you would bind to that event:

```
$("#signature").bind('change', function(e){ /* 'e.target' will refer
to div with "#signature" */ })
```

> Event is emitted asynchronously through a "thread" ( setTimeout(..., 3) ) so you don't need to wrap your event handler into "thread" of any kind, as jSignature widget will go on and will not be waiting for you to be done with your custom event handler logic.

Couldn't you just set a flag variable that gets set to true on the first `change` event? That would indicate that *something* is written into the area

Comment: I am digging it from past 10 days. `getData` returns some junk data if empty canvas. And it varies not constant value also

Comment: Does it return different data even if you specify the same data format each time?

Comment: It always return something like this even if it empty panel ...'image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABM4AAAGaCAYAAAD3rg8TAAAHuklEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQZ/oAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: Ok, but the most important part is if it always returns the **same** data when its empty? If it does, then you can compare your data to the "empty" data set. I they are not the same then it is not empty

Comment: Even-though it is empty it is different data... That might be canvas issue

Comment: Oh that's a bummer. Did you look in to the `change` event I mentioned in my last edit?

Comment: That worked like a charm... Actually It has an undo stock. when ever the event called i am increasing the hidden value to 1. So there I have to decrement value by 2. Because even is called 2 time when undo is called.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the base30 vector if any points are there.

```
var isSignatureProvided=$sigdiv.jSignature('getData','base30')[1].length>1?true:false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, part using roch code : 
it basically assigns the signature to a hidden textarea before submitting for validation:

```
<div id="signatureparent">
<div id="signature"></div>
<label for='signature_capture' class='error'></label>
</div>
<span style="visibility:hidden;">
<textarea name="signature_capture" class="required" id="signature_capture"></textarea> 
</span> 


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var isSignatureProvided=$('#signature').jSignature('getData','base30')[1].length>1?true:false;
    if (isSignatureProvided) {
        var $sigdiv = $("#signature");
        var datapair = $sigdiv.jSignature("getData", "svgbase64");
        var data = $('#signature').jSignature('getData');
        $("#signature_capture").val(data);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no of existing answers worked for me. On my site I have two methods of inputting a signature: manual and jSignature('importData', imgBase64)
Testing of jSignature('getData', 'native') worked only for manual drawing. And nothing worked for the image way.
The solution appeared to be simple. Just test the canvas element. It probably won't work for IE9 but who cares. Here is it in TypeScript:

```
isSignatureBlank() {       
    var canvas = <any>$('#signatureElem').find("canvas")[0];
    if (!canvas) return true;
    this.emptyCanvas = this.emptyCanvas || document.createElement('canvas');
    this.emptyCanvas.width = canvas.width;
    this.emptyCanvas.height = canvas.height;

    return canvas.toDataURL() == this.emptyCanvas.toDataURL();
}
```

Adopted from here: [How to check if a canvas is blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386707/how-to-check-if-a-canvas-is-blank)

Answer (score 0):

Search the code in your javascript file. Check when they are hiding 'Undo Stroke' block

```
t.dataEngine.data.length
```

That will help you finding how many stroke is made to the signature panel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this (assuming your signature fields are of class 'signature')...

```
$('.signature').each(function (index) {
    var datapair = $(this).jSignature("getData", "svgbase64");
    if (datapair[1].length > 1000 ) {
        // Signature is valid; do something with it here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer:

```
if($sigdiv.jSignature('getData', 'native').length == 0) {
  alert('Please Enter Signature..');
}
```

produced the following error:

```
$sigdiv.jSignature(...) is undefined
```

So I would suggest using:

```
if(typeof($sigdiv.jSignature('getData', 'native')) != 'undefined') {
  alert('Please Enter Signature..');
}
```