# How to check if a canvas is blank?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I check, if a HTML5 canvas is blank or has colored pixels. Is there a fast method?

```
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 93):

**Faster: Using [`context.getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) to find "colored" pixels (non-zero values)**

```
// returns true if all color channels in each pixel are 0 (or "blank")
function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
  return !canvas.getContext('2d')
    .getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data
    .some(channel => channel !== 0);
}
```

As [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386707/how-to-check-if-a-canvas-is-blank/17386803#comment96825186_17386803) points out, you can get even better performance by enumerating over a [`Uint32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array) of pixels instead of each color channel in every pixel.

```
// returns true if every pixel's uint32 representation is 0 (or "blank")
function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const pixelBuffer = new Uint32Array(
    context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data.buffer
  );

  return !pixelBuffer.some(color => color !== 0);
}
```

**Slower: Comparing data URLs with a blank canvas**

```
function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
  const blank = document.createElement('canvas');

  blank.width = canvas.width;
  blank.height = canvas.height;

  return canvas.toDataURL() === blank.toDataURL();
}
```

[Benchmark](https://jsbench.me/e3jsy70r9c/1)

***Demo***

```js
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const blank = isCanvasBlank(document.getElementById('canvas'));

  alert(blank ? 'blank' : 'not blank');
});

document.getElementById('draw').addEventListener('click', function() {
  drawOnCanvas(document.getElementById('canvas'));
});

document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

  canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});

function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const pixelBuffer = new Uint32Array(
    context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data.buffer
  );

  return !pixelBuffer.some(color => color !== 0);
}

function drawOnCanvas(canvas) {
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.fillStyle = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16);

  context.fillRect(Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height));
}
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button id="check"> Check </button>
<button id="draw"> Draw </button>
<button id="clear"> Clear </button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: You have canvas.width twice.

Comment: I spent a good 20 minutes figuring out why this failed, since I copied the function from the JSFiddle and the came back here and see everything correct, the JSFiddle is WRONG, it has the 2 widths as mentioned by @wbt11a.

Comment: Yikes! Sorry about that. I've updated the link in the answer.

Comment: Hi..I tried your solution, but it does not work when fabric.js creates the canvas element.Pls check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660743/check-if-canvas-is-blank-in-fabric-js. Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I think this fiddle work for you..http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/rX572/

Comment: this method is very slow when canvas size is big. i tested this on a canvas with size 1800x2800 and there was a noticeable delay even in dev environment with an i7 processor.. and i was trying to make it for mobile devices.

Comment: @devashish what's your use case? This is definitely a brute force method.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst i have a scaled down canvas on an app for mobile devices. at any time, the size of the canvas is at least 1300px+ width (and similarly large numbers for height). while in development of the app, i was noticing a significant lag whenever a blank canvas comparison was being made. now even though it is slow, this seems to be the only way to do it for now. maybe sometime in future we will have a built in method to check this.

Comment: @Devashish I added a new method which according to the benchmark seems to be faster.

Comment: You can get even faster by checking over an Uint32Array instead of checking the Uint8Clamped one: https://jsbench.me/e3jsy70r9c/1

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst great solution, this one is! Uint32Array solution is indeed very fast. thanks!

Comment: for some reason, I had to check if color !== 4294967295 too