# Check if Canvas is blank in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I want to check every 5 seconds if my `Canvas` element is blank.

I followed the solution from the link below, but its not working.

[how-to-check-if-a-canvas-is-blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386707/how-to-check-if-a-canvas-is-blank)

The above link works for plain `canvas` element **BUT NOT** for the one that `fabric.js` creates.

Here is the [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z44grvsq/) that works **without** `Fabric.js`

Here is my **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3c79L1t8/)** that **DOES NOT WORK** when `Fabric.js` creates the canvas.

Comment: it is because you have given background color as white, if you remove that it works.

Comment: A FabricJS canvas becomes "not empty" when you execute the `canvas.add(something)` command. So you can create a global `isEmpty` variable that starts out as true before you add anything and is set to false whenever you execute `canvas.add` in your code.

Comment: @markE: I am not using canvas.add until user performs some actions

Comment: Amazingly, what @KeyurSakaria suggested works, but then how do I make the canvas visible to the user without filling the background color?

Comment: Add background image to the div behind the canvas. That should do it.

Arrange the div and canvas. give z-index to the canvas so that it is in front.

Comment: @Abhinav. That's the point! When the user performs some action you respond with `canvas.add` and that's the exact moment that the canvas becomes not empty. Your alternative method of using `.toDataURL` might also work but it is relatively inefficient.

Comment: @markE : When the user performs some action, the canvas is obviously not empty but when user does not perform any action(i.e immediately after the browser loads), why is it still not empty?

Comment: @downvoter: Why downvote? Please explain

Comment: @KeyurSakaria: hey thanx mate..your suggestion worked.May be you could post it as an answer,i ll accept it

Comment: Well on it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you have given background color as white, if you remove that it works

Comment: Yes, Keyur answer is correct. Here I mention a small thing can reduce the code to check Canvas is empty or not by Fabric JS. Because you write some more code to check is empty or not. canvas.isEmpty() It will return a boolean. :)