# Trying to determine whether canvas is blank or not with javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using the solution from: [How to check if a canvas is blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386707/how-to-check-if-a-canvas-is-blank) but it's not working. My blank canvas URL does not match the newly created canvas URL and I cannot figure out why. They are the same dimensions and everything but their .toDataURL return different things so there is no way for me to tell if it has been drawn in. Below is an example of what happens when I do .toDataURL on my blank canvas and .toDataURL on the newly created canvas, as you can see they differ as you continue along.

```
data:image/png;base64,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

data:image/png;base64,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
```

For reference here is the function:

```
function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
    var blank = document.createElement('canvas');
    blank.width = canvas.width;
    blank.height = canvas.height;

    return canvas.toDataURL() == blank.toDataURL();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the resulting images you have are different. The first one has a white background and the other is transparent.

This is causing the difference.

this is a quick way to fill the new canvas.

```
function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
    var blank = document.createElement('canvas');
    blank.width = canvas.width;
    blank.height = canvas.height;

    var ctx = blank.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blank .width, blank .height);
    return canvas.toDataURL() == blank.toDataURL();
}
```

or use same function as the fiddle. `blank.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

```
function isCanvasBlank(canvas) {
    var blank = document.createElement('canvas');
    blank.width = canvas.width;
    blank.height = canvas.height;

    blank.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    return canvas.toDataURL() == blank.toDataURL();
}
```

Comment: The goal of the function is to test if my canvas element is blank, so it creates a new element to test against since it will always be blank, I see that the new element is transparent, is there a way I can modify this function to give me a blank canvas with a white background?