# Floating clone does not show in chrome if dragged element contains a chartjs component

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, chart.js, sortablejs, vuedraggable

#### Codesand box link

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-qoo66

#### Step by step scenario

I am building a dashboard where each draggable tile of a grid contains a graph. The graphs are drawn using chart.js. Although I am able to change the order of the tiles by dragging and dropping, the floating reference tile of the tile being dragged does not show up if the tile contains a chart.js graph. This only occurs in Chrome Browser. For Firefox and Edge browsers it works fine.

#### Actual Solution

The only found solution is to hide the chart before dragging.

#### Expected Solution

It would be amazing if I can avoid hiding the charts while dragging the tiles.

The results for firefox and chrome are shown below. The flashing glitches is some bug from the screen recording tool, disregard that.

**Result in Firefox67 (Arch Linux)**
[image: firefox-vuedraggable-opt]

**Result in Chrome74 (Arch Linux) Incognito window without any extension**
[image: chome-vuedraggable-opt]

#### Visual results for different browsers from example available at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-qoo66).

Both results were achieved using Chrome74 and Firefox67 running on Arch Linux.
I had the same results for Chrome in Windows, but can't confirm the version now.

I also tried Chrome75 for MacOS. The floating tile was shown, however it was dislocated outside of the page frame when charts were enabled.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with ChartJS. Even setting the drag image to the element using `dataTransfer.setDragImage()` does not work. And using Sortable's fallback `forceFallback: true` shows the element but with a blank space where the chart should be. It is probably because Sortable cannot clone what is in the canvas, and Chrome is not letting it be the drag image.

Comment: Thanks @OwenM, that sounds a good diagnosis of the problem and forceFallback could even be a temporary solution for my problem. I wonder why Firefox and Edge are able to clone the canvas and Chrome cannot? Also, as I mentioned, Chrome on MacOS manages to clone the canvas but the dragged element is dislocated to the left.

Is it possible to catch errors when Sortable fails to clone the canvas? So far the failed attempts a silent.

Cheers

Comment: Posted it as an answer since it wouldn't fit in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank @OwenM for his time and help.
After some back and forth conversation with him at the [Vue.Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) repository page [Issue 664](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/664) he pointed the way to right solution and solved some final issues we ended up facing.

I am publishing the link to a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-qoo66) that contains the final solution.
Although there is some room for some package fixes, the solution solves my current problem and I can move on.

Thanks once again @OwenM, really appreciate it.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of is this:

- You use `forceFallback: true` and define a onStart event in Sortable
- In that event, you use `Sortable.ghost` (the ghost element) and check if it has a canvas inside it
- If it does not, then the graph is not there. If it does, you can check if it is empty by using one of the methods described here: [How to check if a canvas is blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386707/how-to-check-if-a-canvas-is-blank)

Comment: I am now using `forceFallback: isChrome()` where `isChrome` is a method that detects if the browser is chrome and `fallbackOnBody: true` because the default floating clone for Chrome, at least on Linux, has a fairly poor performance for all other existing elements within the tile of my real application. In Firefox and Edge it works just fine. However `fallbackOnBody` removes the chart from the tile. That brings me to a question. Could we skip the default behaviour of the floating clone to be a onBody element such as for fallbackOnBody, but without removing the chart from the tile?

Comment: Answering my last comment... For `fallbackOnBody` the chart canvas is partially copied, but it seems that no data is passed. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: We can talk on Github now