# How to check a canvas image is pure black or pure white

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

How can I test a canvas image is pure black or white by JavaScript without loop through every pixels? Are there any solutions?

Comment: Possibly a related post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17386803/9824103. Under the hood it's definitely O(n) pixels but you don't have to write out a loop yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Well essentially this solution "checks" each pixel by calculating the rgba sum of all pixel. This is not a manual check though:

```
// getting image data of canvas
imgData = canvasRenderingContext.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// get sum of r+g+b+a of all pixels
let sum = imgData.data.reduce(function(a, b){return a + b;}, 0);

// if sum is zero => Black, else if sum is the multiplication of pixel amount and 765 (3*255) it is pure white.
console.log(sum > 0 ? (sum >= canvas.width*canvas.height*765 ? "Canvas is pure white." : "Canvas is not pure black or white") : "Canvas is pure black.");
```

Comment: Doing a sum operation would cost more operations than just a logical check with .some() or .every(). It's not as good, performance wise.